# Login and navigate to next page when credentials received

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to navigate to the next page if the credentials and token are received. This is a react app and I am using react router to navigate to the other pages. Could you please help me understand what is needed to navigate to the next page? Can I use the hook useNavigate to only submit the login form if the credentials match the database? I included the code from the login.jsx page and the users-service.js file.

Login.jsx and users-service.js shown below

**Login.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button"

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {login} from '../utilities/users-service'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Login = () => {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState("We'll never share your email with anyone else.")
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    email:'',
    password:'',
})

const handleChange = e => {
    setCredentials({...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

//submit

let navigate = useNavigate()

const handleSubmit = async e => {
e.preventDefault()
try{
console.log("didi----------", credentials)
  
  login(credentials)  
  navigate('/workouts', {replace: true})
  
}catch(e){

  setMessage('log in failed -Try again')
}
}



return (
<Form className='mx-auto w-50 border p-3' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
        <Form.Label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">Email</Form.Label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name='email'
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={credentials.email}/>
<Form.Text className="text">{message}
  
</Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>

    <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
  <Form.Label  htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</Form.Label>
  <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name='password'
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={credentials.password} />
</Form.Group>
<Button className="mb-3" variant="primary" type="submit" >
Sign In
</Button>
</Form>
)
}

export default Login
```

**users-service.js**

```
 import axios from "axios"
 import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"


const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users'

export const login = async credentials => {

try {
    console.log('We are in user-serviced', credentials)
    const token = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, credentials)

    console.log(token.data)
    //Persist then token using the Window local storage 
    //setItem() first argument is the property name and the second argument is the value
    localStorage.setItem('token', token.data)
   getToken()
   
   

 } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
 }
}

export const getToken = () =>{

//use property/key/field name to grab our token
const token =localStorage.getItem('token')
//getItem() return null if there is no key
if(!token) return null
//console.log('grabing', token)

//Parse our token, split using the "." to isolate our payload and use logic to handle our exp date
//After we decode our token using atob() which decodes encryted base64 string into a JS object
//JWT is encryted in base64   
const payload = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))
console.log(payload)

//JWT's expiration is in seconds, not milliseconds
//
if(payload.exp < Date.now() / 1000){
localStorage.removeItem('token')
return null
}
return token
}

export const getUser = () => {
const token = getToken()
return token ? JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1])).user : null
}
```

Comment: `login(credentials)` take this to any variable and return true on success and false on failed and on behalf of variable redirect user.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your return value from `login(credentials)` in a variable then check whether token (or token.data in your case) exists to navigate:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  const token = await login(credentials)
  if (token.data) {
    navigate('/workouts')
  }
}
```

Don't forget to return some value from your `login(credentials)`:

```
export const login = async credentials => {
  try {
    const token = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, credentials)
    console.log(token.data)
    localStorage.setItem('token', token.data)
    return token
   } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
   }
}
```

For your last question, no, useNavigate has nothing to do with your database. Check out the documentation:

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate